# Efficient way to compute min/max

Tags: nash-equilibrium, computational-algebra

I have a function:
\begin{equation*}
f(a_1,\ldots,a_7,b_1,\ldots,b_4)=-\tfrac12 a_1 + a_1 b_1+\tfrac12 a_1 b_2-\tfrac12 a_1 a_2 b_2 + 2 a_1 a_2 - \tfrac32 a_1 a_2 b_1 - \tfrac12 a_4 + a_4 b_1 + \tfrac12 a_4 a_5 + \tfrac12 a_4 a_5 b_2 - a_4 a_5 b_1 + \tfrac32 a_6 - \tfrac12 a_6 b_3 + \tfrac12 a_6 b_4 + \tfrac32 a_7 - \tfrac32 a_7 b_3 - \tfrac12 a_7 b_4
\end{equation*}

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\forall i: 0 \le a_i \le 1, & \forall j: 0 \le b_j \le 1
\end{array}$$
Two players are playing a game, where player $A$ is trying to maximize the function by picking $a_i$, and player $B$ is trying to minimize it by picking $b_j$. What's the Nash equilibrium?
What's the most efficient way to compute this (e.g., in Mathematica or something else), especially when you have a lot more variables?

Comment: Your terminology is non-standard and very confusing. Could you try to explain what you mean in plain language? Where does probability come in? Is there a random process? If so, what random variables are you looking at, with what distributions?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for the confusion.
Probabilities are picked by the players, but you can just think of them as reals [0.0, 1.0].
The goal for player A is to maximize the function. Player B's goal is to minimize it. The way the game works is player A picks "a" values, then player B picks "b" values.

Comment: As I indicated in my answer below, if player $A$ picks even one number that's not zero, then player $B$ can make the expression take on any value whatsoever. Can you see why?

Comment: Yeah, I'll think about it more tonight and see if I'm phrasing the question accurately, and if your answer makes sense.
Another way to think about it is: I'm looking for a nash equilibrium.

Comment: This is an entirely different question. In the original question, player $A$ went first, and it was thus reasonable to assume that player $B$ knew player $A$'s move. Looking for a Nash equilibrium is something else.

Comment: Hmm, it's not clear to me that it is or that this phrasing will come up with a different solution, but this is definitely a better way to state it.

Comment: No, I don't think it changes anything, really. Check my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Revised answer:

The restriction that $\forall i: 0\le a_i,b_i \le 1$ limits things rather severely. Player $B$ will always choose $0$ for all positive-coefficient terms (this will be best for $B$ regardless of what $A$ may do). Player $A$ will always choose $0$ for all negative-coefficient terms (this will be best for $A$ regardless of what $B$ may do). So the function will always have a value of $0$ in a Nash equilibrium. There are, however, infinitely many equilibria, as it doesn't matter what $A$ chooses for positive-coefficient terms or what $B$ chooses for negative-coefficient ones.

Comment: See the rephrased question. It's not obvious to me that the best player A can do is 0.0. Also, it's not obvious that $\forall i: a_i=0.0 \lor a_i=1.0$

Comment: See my revised and cleared up post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483727/effecient-way-to-find-optimal-solution-in-a-2-player-game